# How can I write select count in Linq-to-SQL?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm beginner in Linq to SQL. I want to write this SQL Server query to count how many repeat field x:

```
SELECT COUNT ([activity_no])
FROM provinces_status;
```

How can I write that query in Linq-to-SQL way? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.Count()` with the linq to sql syntax,

```
(from p in provinces_status 
 select p.activity_no)
 .Count();
```

If you don't have a where clause or addtional filters just `provinces_status.Count()` would also work.

You can refer this **[MSDN Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt693024.aspx)** to start with LINQ.